# Why isn't my regex for at least 1 uppercase working?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I'm trying to make a create user thing in asp, and ofcourse i want to use regex so i'm sure its a good password they are entering. I've tried many things but still, every single FKIN time its says I still need to enter at least 1 uppercase eventhough my pass pretty much consist of Uppercase...

The regex for the Uppercase is the third one.

CODE :

```
        <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btnCreateUser">  
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gebruikersnaam</td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUsername" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtUsername" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfUsername" runat="server" ErrorMessage="U heeft geen gebruikersnaam ingevoerd.<br />"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Wachtwoord</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPassword" />  
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfPassword" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<br />U heeft geen wachtwoord ingevoerd.<br />"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat=server display=dynamic
                            ControlToValidate="txtPassword" foreColor="Red"
                            ErrorMessage="<br />Het wachtwoord moet minstens 1 cijfer bevatten. <br />"
                            ValidationExpression="(?=.*\d)$" />
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat=server display=dynamic
                              ControlToValidate="txtPassword" foreColor="Red"
                              ErrorMessage="Het wachtwoord moet minimaal uit 6 tekenen bestaan. <br />" 
                              ValidationExpression="(.{8,})$" />
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat=server display=dynamic
                              ControlToValidate="txtPassword" foreColor="Red"
                              ErrorMessage="Het wachtwoord moet minimaal 1 hoofdletter bevatten.<br />" 
                              ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[A-Z])$" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Naam</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDisplayName" />  
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtDisplayName" ForeColor="Red" ID="rfDisplay" runat="server" ErrorMessage="U heeft geen display naam ingevoerd.<br />"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label Text="" ID="lblNewUserStatus" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button Text="Aanmaken" runat="server" ID="btnCreateUser" OnClick="btnCreateUser_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
         </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])$"
```

This should be `^(?=.*[A-Z]).*$"` .

```
                          ^^
```

Your original regex expects an empty string `^$`,and the lookahead wants a `capital letter` so in effect it won't match anything.

You can combine all your regexes in one:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$
```

Comment: @Anona the problem persists with other regexs of urs as well.Correct them as well and you can apply all in one go as well

Comment: I suggest `^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z]).{8,}$`. I am on the contrast principle kick today :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `.*` in your validation pattern:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z]).*$
            ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to require that there's at least one uppercase letter, `[A-Z]` is all the regex you need.  Those multiple-lookahead password regexes you see everywhere are for doing the whole validation in one shot.  Performing separate regex matches as you are, it's dead simple:

- `[0-9]` matches a string that has at least one digit
- `[A-Z]` matches a string with at least one uppercase ASCII letter, and
- `.{8}` matches a string with at least eight characters.